# How to create an attribute that contains current hour?

Tags: apache-nifi

How to create an attribute that would contain current hour in 24 hours format?

I tried to use `EvaluateJsonPath` and `UpdateAttribute` and created a new parameter `current_hour` with the following value `${now():toNumber():Divide(60*60*1000)}`.

It seems that this part of the expression `:Divide(60*60*1000)` does not work properly.

If now it's 15:35, I need to get `15`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with `${now():format("HH")}`.